# Add new contact in Xero using python FASTAPI

Tags: python, xero-api

I am trying to add a new contact in Xero using python FASTAPI:

**define a new contact**

```
    contact = {
                "Contacts": [
                    {
                        "Name": "24 locks",
                        "FirstName": "Ben",
                        "LastName": "Bowden",
                        "EmailAddress": "ben.bowden@24locks.com",
                        "ContactPersons": [
                            {
                            "FirstName": "John",
                            "LastName": "Smith",
                            "EmailAddress": "john.smith@24locks.com",
                            "IncludeInEmails": "true"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
```

**Call xero API**

```
    get_url = 'https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Contacts'

    response = requests.post(get_url,
                           headers = {
                               'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
                               'Xero-tenant-id': xero_tenant_id,
                               'Accept': 'application/json'
                           },
                           data = contact
                )

    json_response = response.json()
```

**I get the following error:**

```
{'ErrorNumber': 17, 'Type': 'NoDataProcessedException', 'Message': 'No data has been processed for this endpoint. This endpoint is expecting Contact data to be specifed in the request body.'}
```

Someone can help please ?

You can assume that `access_token` and `xero_tenant_id` are correct as I am using them for other methods and they works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `json = contact` instead of `data = contact` or set header `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

[Because](https://programmerall.com/article/98991782461/)

> `data` for `dict` When not specified `content-type`, The default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`,

Comment: json = contact worked!!Thank you